# Finish all Activities above certain Activity, but only if that certain Activity is on stack

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

I have to manage a situation: from current Activity (`D`) I have to kill all Activities above some certain Activity (`X`). I have to handle 2 cases:

1. `A - X - C - D`
2. `A - B - C - D`

As you can see in 1st situation `X` is on stack so after killing stack should look like: `A - X`.

In 2nd situation `X` is not on stack so stack should remain intact.

What I tried so far is : in `D` I send LocalBroadcastManager to "everywhere". I register for that LocalBroadcast in `X` only. So if `X` is on stack it'll receive LocalBroadcast and I try to kill "all Activities above myself" via:

```
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent intents = new Intent(XActivity.this, XActivity.class);
            intents.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
```

But this fails with:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent
```

Comment: Haha, Thanks to my eye. Accept if helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `intent` to `intents` :

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent intents = new Intent(XActivity.this, XActivity.class);
        intents.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intents);  //<-- here
    }
};
```

Comment: whoa! I'd never spot that. My eyes are getting older. Thx.